# Google Maps API shows location, but doesn't center

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working with the Google Maps API in Android Studio 2.2.3 and for some reason the location button works, but it doesn't center. Furthermore, I get a toast with the message that there no location was found.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    getLocationPermission();
}

private void getDeviceLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {

            Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);


                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    }
}
```

The above code is what I to believe the code for finding the location, and then positioning the camera to that given location. I do not get any errors and when I set the LocationButton to true, and then click on it, it does center to my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing that code to

```
    private void getDeviceLocation(){
    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
            Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: location found!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        float currentZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;//edit (added line)

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                                currentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));//edit (changed line)

                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }catch (SecurityException e){

    }
}
```

I managed so get a return with a location, after I manually set the location for the device because for some reason the location doesn't get determined rightaway. 
For now the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code.
It didn't work for me but I solved the problem.
Here is the correct code.

```
private void getDeviceLocation(){
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
            Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){
                        Toast.makeText(DriverMapActivity.this, "Task is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        mLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
                        moveCamera(mLatLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(DriverMapActivity.this, "Task is unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "SecurityException Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

So, if your app is crashing, you might wanna try this instead.